# Laravel application, connection is refused while the concurrent client connection is crossing 200

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a web application using laravel framework. As part of load test, we hit the application with parallel connections through a tool. We found that the application is not accepting more than 200 concurrent connections at a time. Beyond the 200 concurrent connections, the http connection is getting refused.

I have configured more than 200 (upto 1000) as throttle count in api.php. But it doesnt resolve the issue. If I configure less than 200, then it perfectly works up to the throttle count. But while going beyond 200, the parallel connection always fails to the client.

Answer (score 0):

In your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` class generally is where you would add global rate limiting by using the `configureRateLimiting` method, so it should look something like this for your case.

```
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
 
/**
 * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('global', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(1000); //add any number of calls per minute that fit your criteria
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it was not working.